# My multicast server can only receive message from a sender on the same subnet

Tags: c, sockets, multicast, subnet

I have a multicast client and server running on 2 different hosts, which are directly connected with an Ethernet cable. The client IP is 192.168.1.1  and the multicast group is 226.1.1.1:4321. If my server IP is 192.168.1.2 , the client correclty received the server messages
But If I set my server host IP to 192.168.2.2 the client didn't see any messages.

if I run tcpdump on the client host, I'm able to see the messages from the server while my client.c didn't see anything

2 workaround seems to work :

1- if I send a single message from a third host with IP 192.168.1.3, it somehow unlock everything and my client.c can now see every next message from 192.168.2.2 server

2-If I change the client host netmask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0 the client can now see the messages from 192.168.2.2 server

```
/*******CLIENT*******/

struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if(sd < 0)
   {
      perror("Opening datagram socket error");
      exit(1);
   }
   else
   printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");

   {
   int reuse = 1;
   if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
   {
      perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
      close(sd);
      exit(1);
   }
   else
      printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");
   }

   memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
   localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
   localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
   localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
   {
      perror("Binding datagram socket error");
      close(sd);
      exit(1);
   }
   else
      printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");

   group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
   group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
   if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
   {
      perror("Adding multicast group error");
      close(sd);
      exit(1);
   }
   else
   printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");


   datalen = sizeof(databuf);
   while(1) 
   {
      if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)
      {
         perror("Reading datagram message error");
         close(sd);
         exit(1);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Reading datagram message...OK.\n");
         printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

```
/******SERVER******/

struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
int sd;

char databuf[10] = "balblabla";

int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{

   sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if(sd < 0)
   {
      perror("Opening datagram socket error");
      exit(1);
   }
   else
      printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");


   memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
   groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
   groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
   groupSock.sin_port = htons(4321);


   localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.2");
   if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)
   {
      perror("Setting local interface error");
      exit(1);
   }
   else
      printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");

   reloop:
   if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
   {      
      perror("Sending datagram message error");
   }
   else
      printf("Sending datagram message...OK\n");
   sleep(1);

   goto reloop;

   return 0;
}
```

Why tcpdump can see the messages while my client.c didn't see anything ? Is there a socket configuration that I missed ?

Any advice would be appreciate

Comment: you sure that is not a problem with the ARP cache? Try flushing after you change the IP adresses.

Comment: I just did it, and unfortunately, it didn't help